# CKEditor page not visible after EDIT

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor as WYSWYG tool in my php APP. I am loading some HTML documents in CKEDITOR and they appear correctly. User can edit the contains of this HTML and can SAVE IT (which goes to DB). I have also provided button to load edited contains which were saved in DB, HTML source for these edited documents is seen in CKEditor (when source button is clicked) but HTML page is not seen - it comes as blank. If I copy the edited source in file and save it as HTML then local browser shows the pages correctly- so to confirm that edited HTML code does not have any errors, but CKEditor show it as blank.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: could you please post your code at here ?

Comment: This is what I am doing in Javascritp

Comment: // remove the previous instance of editor
if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor']) {
 CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].destroy(true);
}

// set the  data for the editor in TEXTAREA
$("#editor").val(target_body);
      
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
   height: 300,
   fullPage: true,
   allowedContent: true,
   resize_minHeight: 300
});

Comment: you may consider updating your question in more detail, including posting the code.